# Indexed memory pointer arrays versus indirect integer index arrays in ANSI C

Tags: c, pointers, gcc, indexing

The statement

```
a[i] += a[j] * a[k];
```

will be executed thousands of times in a loop that may be executed thousands to millions of times. The indices `i`, `j`, and `k`, representing random access to entries in `a`, could be set by statements

```
i = i_index[l];
j = j_index[l];
k = k_index[l];
```

where `l` is the index of the `for` loop. The integer arrays `i_index`, `j_index`, and `k_index` are set at the beginning of the program and may be changed occasionally.

Memory pointer arrays are an alternative. For example

```
*ap1[l] += *ap2[l] * (*ap3[l]);
```

where the memory pointer arrays `ap1`, `ap2`, and `ap3` were set up in advance to point to the locations originally identified by the `i_index`, `j_index`, and `k_index` arrays. They may also be changed occasionally.

The first method looks cleaner than the second, but it would seem to be slower unless there were some way to provide additional information to the compiler. It seems that the GCC compiler in XCode would have no way to discover in advance that `i_index`, `j_index`, and `k_index` or `ap1`, `ap2`, and `ap3` would most of the time be unchanging. Any way to give the gcc compiler a heads up to improve performance?

Comment: Have you determined that the clean solution **is** slower?

Comment: Start out by writing the code as clearly and as straight forward as you can. Odds are, changes after that won't make it any faster.

Comment: Also writing cleaner code makes it easier to understand, maintainable and less prone to errors. As to make things faster do profiling first.

Comment: You don't need all those parantheses in the second version, because `[]` has higher precedence than unary `*` - so `*ap1[l] += *ap2[l] * *ap3[l];` is fine.

Comment: Can you arrange the code so access to a is as linear as possible?  That will speed things up the most IMO.  If not, look at a profiler run that tells you about cache thrashing and then try to reduce the thrashing as much as possible.

Answer (score 3):

It is unlikely that you will find an option to have the compiler effectively cache the pointer values in the first version of the code that you are explicitly caculating and saving in the second version of the code.  This is because the compiler would need to emit code to generate and save a very large data structure to cache those values, and this is not typical compiler behaviour.

However, depending on the architecture you're targetting this probably won't matter.  Many architectures have an  "indirect base + index" addressing mode, which is what would be used for the accesses to `a` in `a[i] += a[j] * a[k];`, and on modern cores these don't have any performance penalty over a plain "indirect" addressing mode (that is - one instruction will multiple `i` by the size of `a[0]`, add it to the base address of `a` and dereference the result).  Profile on your target architecture and see.

One thing that *might* well improve things, with either version, is to use an array of `struct`s instead of three seperate arrays, so that the three values needed for each value of `l` are kept contiguously in memory:

```
i = index[l].i;
j = index[l].j;
k = index[l].k;
```

or

```
*ap[l].i += *ap[l].j * *ap[l].k;
```

This will mean that your code is making one linear traverse through the `index` or `ap` array, rather than three simultaneous linear traverses, which should help the prefetcher to recognise what you're doing.

Comment: The assignment statement `*ap1[l] += *ap2[l] * (*ap3[l]);` is just one of a number of similar statements in various `for` loops and involving different data arrays. The processing algorithms represent sparse matrix operations performed on permuted data where the data cannot be copied, stored, or accessed sequentially. The primary goal is to minimize computational overhead, because computer runtimes can be excessive. In this case, reducing computational overhead will alway trump ease of programming and debugging.